# Why does the following frame not display the OK button(Java)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I wrote a simple program to see the effects of the add and remove methods in java and for whatever reason the following code does not display the OK button. Can anyone tell me why? I am thoroughly confused as it should work just fine.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyFrameWithComponents {
        public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Adding and removing components.");
        JButton OK = new JButton("OK");
        JButton Cancel = new JButton("Cancel");

        frame.add(OK);
        frame.add(Cancel);

        frame.remove(Cancel);

        frame.setSize(400 , 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is typically better to add all components at start-up and enable or disable them (or their `Action`) as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems your problem in next:

Your `JFrame` has a `BorderLayout` as default you call `frame.add(OK);` for adding your button as default to `Center` of container, then you call `frame.add(Cancel);` it "override" your first addition, because of that you don't see your button, because you delete cancel button.

For example, if you use `frame.add(OK,BorderLayout.WEST);` you see your button.

Also read more about [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) and [`BorderLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the size and the location >>

```
    JButton OK = new JButton("OK");
    OK.setSize(50,50);
    OK.setLocation(175, 170);
```

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Comment: you are also wrong his `JFrame` has a layoutManager he must not to set size and position

Comment: @alex2410 i can't see that "layoutManager" in his code can you please show us ?

Comment: His frame has borderlayout as default